# How to linearly interpolate through an array in SAS?

Tags: sas

bear with me! This is a project that I've been working on for awhile, trying many things and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Below is the existing code that I'm using to create a new table. The existing output table (claims.simulation_ISLPx) is also below.

What I want to do is take an "array" of members (5,6,8,10,12) and run 5 iterations of a process for the 5 member group, 6 iterations for the 6 member group,..., and 12 iterations for the 12 member group.

The "process" should draw a random value from U(0,1) and then linearly interpolate it with the given values in the claims.simulationISLPx table to determine the average claims among the group (it would take the total claims and divide it by 5, 6, 8, 10, or 12).

I have no idea what do add to my code. Any help would be really appreciated.

/*Inputs from Zero-Inflated Lognormal Function and Allowed to Paid Formula */

```
%let P_0 = .25; 
%let Mean = 8.9; 
%let Std_Dev = 1.8;
%let ISL = 50000;
%let Deductible = 1750;
%let COINS = .80; 
%let OOPM = 2000; 
%let Min_Paid = 253.08;
%let Ind_Cap_Claim = 2500000;
%let Iterations = 10;
%let Distribution = 'Lognormal';
%let Member_Count = (5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,400,500)

libname claims 



data simulation; 
    do i = 1 to &Iterations; 
        Px = rand('Uniform',&P_0,1);
        Px1 = rand('Uniform',0,1);/*generate random numbers from 0 to 1*/
            if Px>= %sysevalf(&P_0) then 
        Allowed_Claims = quantile(&Distribution,Px1,%sysevalf(&Mean),%sysevalf(&Std_Dev));  /*inverse of cdf*/
        output; 
    end;
run; 

proc sql;
   create table claims.simulation_ISLPx as 
   select Allowed_Claims, Px1
      from simulation
      order by Allowed_Claims,Px1;
quit;

proc sql; 
alter table claims.simulation_ISLPx add Paid_Claims_NoISL float; 
    update claims.simulation_ISLPx
        set Paid_Claims_NoISL = min(max(0,Allowed_Claims - %sysevalf(&OOPM), min(Allowed_Claims, 
                                %sysevalf(&Min_Paid) + max(Allowed_Claims - %sysevalf(&Deductible)*%sysevalf(&COINS),0))),
                                %sysevalf(&Ind_Cap_Claim));
alter table claims.simulation_ISLPx add Paid_Claims_AfterISL float; 
    update claims.simulation_ISLPx
        set Paid_Claims_AfterISL = min(Paid_Claims_NoISL, %sysevalf(&ISL)); 
alter table claims.simulation_ISLPx add Total_Cost float; 
    update claims.simulation_ISLPx
        set Total_Cost = Paid_Claims_NoISL - Paid_Claims_AfterISL;
quit;

proc sql;
select * from claims.simulation_ISLPx;
run;
quit;
```

**Below is kind of what I thought about doing**

```
%let Member_Count= [5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,400,500]; 


data simulation_interpolation;  
    do i = 1 to &Member_Count[0]; 
    xyz = rand('uniform',0,1);  
        if xyz >= 0 then Px = xyz;
        output;
        end;
        run;
    proc print data= simulation_interpolation;
    run;
```

Comment: Please update your question to include sample input and output datasets. Also, I suggest you learn a bit more about [using arrays in SAS](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/242-30.pdf).

Comment: Hey user667489, unfortunately the sample input, or values used, are internally generated through the 'simulation' step..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to iterate thru a macro string.  Below is one approach I would use based on your example, although there are more efficient methods.  This will convert the Member_Count macro string into a dataset, and that dataset is used to generate the simulations.  Then a PROC SUMMARY is used to average the simulations for each group.

```
%let Member_Count= [5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,400,500]; 

*** GET MACRO STRING AND CONVERT INTO A DATASET - ONE RECORD PER ITEM ***;
data start;
    *** COMPRESS BRACKETS FROM MACRO STRING ***;
    temp = compress("&member_count.", '[]');
    *** COUNT THE NUMBER OF COMMAS IN STRING AND ADD 1 ***;
    n = count(temp, ',') + 1;
    *** LOOP OVER STRING - GET MEMBER_COUNT, CONVERT TO NUMERIC, AND OUTPUT ***;
    do i = 1 to n;
        member_count = input( scan(temp, i), best8.);
        output;
    end;
run;

data simulation_interpolation;  
    set start(keep=member_count);
    do i = 1 to member_count ;
        xyz = rand('uniform',0,1);  
        if xyz >= 0 then Px = xyz;
        output;
    end;
run;

proc print data= simulation_interpolation;
run;

*** USE PROC SUMMARY TO CALCUATE AVERAGE FOR EACH GROUP OF ITERATIONS ***;
proc summary data=simulation_interpolation  nway;
    class member_count;
    var px;
    output out=stats  mean=mean;
run;
```

I’m not sure this is what you want, and I don’t understand your description about interpolation, but hopefully this helps you make progress on your problem.

Comment: Hey SunnyRJ. This is super close to what I need. By interpolation, I mean if Px = .010 and I know the corresponding values of Allowed_Claims where Px = .011 and Px = .009, I can find a linear approximation.